# Отловить нажатие кнопки "minimize" в консоли WinAPI

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Реально ли в консольном приложении C/C++ отловить нажатие кнопки minimize (свернуть)? Спасибо.

Comment: Консольные приложения для этого не предназначены. Почему не хотите создать оконное?

Comment: Ну-с, раз нельзя - то создадим) Просто интересовало, возможно ли вообще такое. В трей-то я свернул, по другой кнопке...Спасибо:)

Comment: чисто теоретически может сработать хук на WndProc окна cmd.exe

Comment: попробую на досуге, действительно, про хуки не думал